# Change construct of class, Java

Tags: java, constructor

I have a class, `LogAnalyzer()` and i want to change the constructor, so it can take an instance of the class `LogfileReader`. This instance will then be analyzed by the `LogAnalyzer` class.

Here is the code for the constructor:

```
public LogAnalyzer()
{ 
    // Create the array object to hold the hourly
    // access counts.
    hourCounts = new int[24];
    // Create the reader to obtain the data.
    reader = new LogfileReader();
}
```

and here is the fields of the `LogAnalyzer` class:

```
// Where to calculate the hourly access counts.
private int[] hourCounts;
// Use a LogfileReader to access the data.
private LogfileReader reader;
```

What should i do ?

Comment: Hint: It's asking you to create a constructor that takes an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class LogAnalyzer() {

private int[]hourCounts;
private LogfileReader reader;

    // version that accepts LogFileReader
    public LogAnalyzer(LogfileReader r){
        hourCounts=new int[24];
        reader=r; // use the passed LogfileReader object, instead of creating one
    }

    // no-argument version
    public LogAnalyzer(){
        hourCounts=new int[24];
        reader=new LogfileReader();
    }

}
```

When you introduce a constructor with arguments, you lose the implicit no-argument constructor, so it's a good idea to create it as well.

Comment: Thank you sir! It helped a lot! This part of the code: reader = r; , is exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors may also have arguments.

```
public LogAnalyzer(LogfileReader r){
    this.reader = r;
    //insert code here
}
```

Comment: How should I initialize the LogfileReader inside of that constructor?